# How to add a new record and not update previous record in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

How do I add a new record and have angular "forget" the new item added after I click the corresponding button.
The ability to add a record works and when I add the new record it display in the table I have, correctly, However my problem is that when I go to add a second record ie I remove the previous input and type something else. This results in the newly added record below to also change.

In short after I add an item to my array I want angular to forget it. How do I accomplish this.

In my controller I have this

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module("mainApp");

    var ordersController = function ($scope,$filter, ordersService,customerService) {
        $scope.orders = [];


    $scope.addOrder = function (newOrder) {


            $scope.orders.push(newOrder);
        }

app.controller("ordersController", ["$scope","$filter", "ordersService","customerService", ordersController]);

}());
```

in my html I have this

```
<div><table>
            <tr>
                <td><input ng-model="item.quantity" type="text" /></td>
               <td><button type="button" ng-click="addOrder(item)">Add Line Item</button></td>
            </tr>
</table></div>
    <div>
<table>
                <tr ng-repeat="order in orders track by $index">
                    <td>
                        {{ order.quantity }}
                    </td>
              </tr>
</table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem might be that you are adding the `newOrder` object to the array  while Angular keeps it's model bound to that object. Try using Angular's copy functionality like this (assuming that you are using Angular 1):

```
$scope.addOrder = function (newOrder) {
        var copiedOrder = angular.copy(newOrder);
        $scope.orders.push(copiedOrder);
    }
```

The documentation for the copy method can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy#!).

Comment: Thank you that worked like a charm :) I had a coworker walk by and help me out but your answer is the shorthand one which I like a lot better. For others I was pushing a pointer to the array thus everytime I updated the model everything else also updated. So in order for it to work you have to create a new object and assign each property or thanks to @J.N. you can simply call angular.copy(yourObject);